# Shared Sub Category

Tags: category, category-tree

I believe I can achieve this with URL rewrites but I cannot seem to get it right. Here is a sample hierarchy:

- Baby Girl

  - Romper (baby-girls/rompers)
  - Onesie (baby-girls/onesies)
- Romper

  - Baby Girl (baby-girls/rompers) <--Need this sub category to resolve to the above
  - Baby Boy
- Onesie

  - Baby Girl (baby-girls/onesies) <--Need this sub category to resolve to the above
  - Baby Boy

So, I have a couple different trees with unique top nodes however the second levels are the same and would like to have a single URL/Content for them for SEO and for ease of management. Is this possible, even if its just through a 301?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with URL rewrites, at least not without custom coding. You would always have some kind of conflict between the rewrite from the category tree and the redirection. Or you end up with some temporary workaround that is gone with the next reindexing of URL rewrites.

The standard Magento way is actually to have multiple categories (like /baby-girls/rompers, /rompers/baby-girls) and maintain them in parallel.

However I'd like to draw your attention to a very promising open source project, currently going on called [`FireGento_FlexCms`](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/FireGento_FlexCms). Its goal is to improve the usability of Magentos CMS overall but one of the features that already exist is linking categories in the category tree to arbitrary URLs - so you could create two dummy categories and link them to the real category. The developers behind this are credible members of the Magento community, so I recommend it without a doubt.